# VSCode /etc/fstab permission denied, no access to network folders

Tags: permissions, shared-folders, visual-studio-code

I installed today's (29.09.2021) version of vscode via the Ubuntu Software Center.
Version:
`1.60.2 7f6ab5485bbc008386c4386d08766667e155244e x64`

I cannot open a folder form a network share, when I navigate to "other locations" in the explorer it just shows my computer.

When I start vscode via the terminal I get:

```
system_key.go:129: cannot determine nfs usage in generateSystemKey: cannot parse /etc/fstab: open /etc/fstab: permission denied
```

Permissions of my fstab file:
[image]

Now, I'm not sure if these permissions are fine, but I wonder if this has anything to do with my problem?

Comment: Is it a snap that you installed?

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes it is